# Creating difficult UI options in HMTL5

Tags: html, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaWAo.png)

How to implement the provided design using Bootstrap. 
Please suggest. :)

Comment: You need to provide code! Have you at least tried to come up with some sort of a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should implement the circle part which is a rectangle with a border-radius 100%, and set relative position.

Then, create three rectangular containers in previously created part with absolute position (top:0, left:50%).